# how to install and configure a mail server debian

Tags: linux, email, debian, sendmail, postfix-mta

I was trying to install on Debian postfix or some mail client to have mails,(its ok if i install a client and it install by itself all the things needed, like postfis and stuffs) Ive read a lot and many tutorials seems to be pretty long, complicated and the worste of all at the end of the configuration just doesnt work anything at my mail, i am novice in this, please, could anybody help me to find a solution a tutorial or give me an explination of how to install it??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question would most likely yield better results on SuperUser instead, however I just did the same thing, only in Fedora. Here is the walkthrough I used:

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Configuring_a_Fedora_Linux_Email_Server

I'm sure you can use it and simply replace 'yum' with 'apt-get'. Good Luck.

Comment: looks very nice! i will try it, I just have one silly question, most of all tutorials say how to install and setup and all, but how to create users? any idea? I tried created linux users (which I th ink its wrong) even if worked, I think may be other way, could you give me any clue please?